# Notepad++ and code completion

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

Is there any way to improve code completion in notepad++?

Currently it supports some kind of "static" code completion and it requires to make a list of instructions and they parameters in xml file or it works on a list of words in open document. I`m looking for something that can read *.h files and make that list automatically and also use variables and functions from current file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have some code completion sections to look at [here](http://cybernetnews.com/2008/06/16/notepad-50-can-auto-complete-code/). But i would mainly suggest you change to an IDE for the programming language because Notepad++ doesn't have any of the benefits you find in a Real IDE. ( Maybe because it's a text-editor and not an IDE ).

Comment: you have to use php Storm its nice IDE if you learn more go to ::

Comment: or just use sublime text!

Answer (score 14):

You don’t need a plugin at all. On the main menu go to Settings->Preferences. Then head on over to the Backup/Auto-Completion tab.  Check the box labeled “Enable auto-completion on each input” and select the “Word completion” option.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible without creating your own plugin.

It might be faster to develop a script that parses your .h files and creates an auto-complete language file for notepad++.

Although a plugin that parsed your include files (for any language) and added them to the auto-complete would be very nice.

Comment: FYI, 3 years later, notepad++'s plugin Ccompletion which does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

No.  [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a text-editor, not an IDE.  Unless you want to extend it yourself, you are not going to do any better than what is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). It has the code completion you're looking for and has project support, and best of all, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when putting on autocomplete in notepad++ you select function completeion instead of word completion and have a tick in the function parameters hint on input as well.